# Apache2 unexpected redirect: Virtualhost DirectoryIndex not serving index.php automatically

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, .htaccess, directoryindex

I have two Apache virtual hosts set up on an Ubuntu 16.04 VPS.

- `site1.example.com` is a properly functioning WordPress site.
- `site2.example.com` is a newly added site with only `index.php` in its document root.

When I visit `site2.example.com` in a browser, it unexpectedly redirects to `site1.example.com` (the WP site).

However, if I visit `site2.example.com/index.php`, `index.php` is displayed as expected.

Here are the contents of the `.conf` files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`:

### site1.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site1.example.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site1.example.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

### site2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName site2.example.com
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site2.example.com/public_html
</VirtualHost>
```

What can I do to get `http://site2.example.com/` to display `index.php` without being explicitly requested in the URL?

If anyone has any suggestions or needs to see another part of my config, please let me know.

Comment: "it unexpectedly redirects" - If you examine the network traffic in the browser, do you see an external 3xx redirect? Make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Comment: @w3dk Clearing the browser cache resolved the problem. Thanks! I was not aware that something in the browser cache could cause this behavior.  I figured requesting a new subdomain url would ensure a request was made to the server.  If you'd like to give a short explanation of what may have happened as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...it unexpectedly redirects to `site1.example.com`

If you are seeing a 3xx redirect, and you don't currently have any external redirects configured then it's possible you are seeing a cached redirect - which appears to have been the case in this instance. Make sure the browser cache is cleared. Any 301 (permanent) redirects are cached hard by the browser - even if only used briefly for testing. (On the other hand, 302 temporary redirects are not cached.)

Note that `site2.example.com/` and `site2.example.com/index.php` are two different URLs and so are cached independently.

Maybe `site2.example.com/` was caught by an earlier canonical domain redirect?